# why does second iteration of for-loop not wait for user input

Tags: for-loop

I am having a problem with a for loop. When I go through the second iteration, the program does not wait for user input. Any help gratefully accepted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dogInfo.h"


main()
{
    struct dogInfo dog[3];  //Array of three structure variable
    int ctr;

    //Get information about dog from the user
    printf("You will be asked to describe 3 dogs\n");
    for (ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr ++)
    {
       printf("What type (breed) of dog would you like to describe for dog #%d?\n", (ctr +1));
       gets(dog[ctr].type);
       puts("What colour is the dog? ");
       gets(dog[ctr].colour);
       puts("How many legs does the dog have? ");
       scanf(" %d", &dog[ctr].legNum);
       puts("How long is the snout of the dog in centimetres? ");
       scanf(" %.2f", &dog[ctr].snoutLen);
       getchar(); //clears last new line for the next loop
    }
```

The header file is as below

```
 struct dogInfo
{
    char type[25];
    char colour[25];
    int legNum;
    float snoutLen;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that gets is not behaving in the way you want it to. You should not be using gets anyway because it is dangerous and [can cause overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).
But fortunately scanf can easily read strings and also allows to specify a format (in this case %24s because you want to read up to 24 chars, because the last char is reserved for the Null-terminator.

The code works like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
struct dogInfo
{
    char type[25];
    char colour[25];
    int legNum;
    float snoutLen;
};

int main()
{
    struct dogInfo dog[3];  //Array of three structure variable
    int ctr;

    //Get information about dog from the user
    printf("You will be asked to describe 3 dogs\n");
    for (ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr ++)
    {
       printf("What type (breed) of dog would you like to describe for dog #%d?\n", (ctr +1));
       scanf("%24s", dog[ctr].type);
       puts("What colour is the dog? ");
       scanf("%24s", dog[ctr].colour);
       puts("How many legs does the dog have? ");
       scanf(" %d", &dog[ctr].legNum);
       puts("How long is the snout of the dog in centimetres? ");
       scanf(" %.2f", &dog[ctr].snoutLen);
       getchar(); //clears last new line for the next loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell me why the first iteration is OK, but for the second iteration C won't wait for user input? Thanks